# Can somebody explain the notation $f \in C^4$

Tags: convergence-divergence, notation, fixed-point-theorems

To give some context the full question is:

Suppose $f \in C^4$ in a interval containing the root $\alpha$ and that Newton’s method gives a sequence of iterates $\{x_k\}$, $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ which converge to $\alpha$. Show that Newton’s method is at least quadratically convergent to $\alpha$ if $f'(\alpha) \ne 0$.
What is $C^4$ here?

Answer (score 1):

The set of $4$ times continuously differentiable functions (i.e. the 4th derivative exists and is continuous).

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html

Comment: And to see an explicit example of a function $f \in C^{k} \setminus C^{k+1}$, consider $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, defined by $$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{rl} x^{k+1}, & x \ge 0, \\ -x^{k+1}, & x < 0. \end{array} \right.$$